# How to center an arbitrary chunk of HTML?

Tags: html, css, centering

For example maybe my HTML is one of the following:

- a `<p>` of text with its width set to 400
- a form with a handful of inputs with no overall width set
- a `<table>` with no overall width set
- or anything else

In other words - before you center any of the above they are naturally to the left. Is it possible to center whatever that HTML is?

**Edit:** Let me clarify more. The chunk of HTML can be anything: inline, block, three divs and 2 ps, 5 tables and a div, a div inside a div, etc..The html chunk doesn't know it's going to be centered and it isn't allowed to center itself. I want something along the lines of - let's wrap this chunk of HTML in a parent div and then use CSS on only the parent div. Something along the lines of that where you're not adjusting the HTML chunk. I want it to horizontally center not vertically. I want it to render just as it would if it were still on the left.

Comment: take a look at my answer. The positioning of #canvas is exactly what you've asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Hey there are two option first is very old option

```
<center>
//your html any element 
</center>
```

but this is very old method

and new option is

you can used to this as like

**css**

```
.ok{
border:solid 1px red;
  width:400px;
  text-align:center;
}
table{
margin:0 auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="ok">

<p>
Hello
</p>

<a href="#">a</a>
<form>
<input type="text">
</form>

  <table border="1">
    <tr><td>hi</td></tr>
  </table>

  </div>
```

Live demo http://tinkerbin.com/j1A3HIK9

Comment: `<center>` is working for me. Is there anything wrong with using it?

Comment: because this is old technology it's used to only news letter

Comment: don't understand, can you say it another way?

Comment: more info  go to this link http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp        ------------------------      http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/linepar/_CENTER.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set an element centrally another element, assign the child element relative positioning or just default positioning (absolute positioning won't do!), give it a fixed width, set its margin to `0 auto`, and it will be centered horizontally inside the parent element. Of course there is no way to center elements vertically, you will have to do it explicitly by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible for all the elements you noted.

Take this HTML:

```
<body>

<div class="canvas">

    <p>This is a really lovely but meaningless piece of text</p>

    <div class="form-container">

        <form>

            <input type="text" name="example" placeholder="Enter some example text" />

        </form>

    </div>

</div>

</body>
```

So we want to centre some elements. Lets start with the containing DIV #canvas and move from there.

```css
/* First a very crude reset on <body> and declare it's dimensions */

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

/* Next we must declare a definitive width of our #canvas to allow
   us to centre itself and elements within it. */

#canvas {
    width:960px;
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 auto; /* This 'auto' on left / right margin centers it
}

/* Note that <p> tags are auto 100% width so centering them is not
   going to do anything with the above technique. Instead: */

#canvas p {
    text-align: center;
}

/* Now form elements, no need to style <form> it is a meta container
   and really shouldn't be used for anything other than that, lets
   style the actual input elements instead */

#canvas form input {
    width: 30%; /* Lets define a width so that we can center it in */
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Hope that helps you.

Comment: nope. not allowed to touch the middle arbitrary chunk. so in your case you can only use CSS on the canvas div and inside that can be anything(this anything doesn't know it's being centered and isn't allowed to center itself).

Comment: You've missed the point. You can do that to ANY positioned element wherever it is, regardless of how nested it is. The above is my example for simplicities sake.

Comment: Try it our Ryan, give a container DIV a width and then give it margin:0 auto. It will be centered to it's parent.

Comment: You're not allowed to set the container DIV width. One of the main goals is to let the inner chunk width determine how it's centered. for example the inner chunk might be 100px, it might be 1100px or there may be no overall width set at all. '<center>' seems to be working as Rohit suggests.

Comment: Could you post an example link or a jsfiddle? <center> is massively deprecated, to use it in modern web design is not a good idea.